# Javascript Audio Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Im trying to develop an javascript based audio editor. It should be possible to record, play and edit an audio file with. Its especially important to visualize the recording audio (realtime) and the selected/uploaded audio file (both of them).
I red alot about the [Web-Audio-API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/?redirect_from_locale=de#toc-volume) and saw a few examples as well, but there are some problems - it only works in chrome/safari so far, it should be run on firefox as well, but it doesnt. So what Im looking for is an crossbrowser API or javascript/jquery libary which provides the called features.

Here are some examples to show u what I mean:
http://plucked.de/ (great tool, but there are many bugs as well)
http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xmyler00/audiee/ (as u can see web audio API doesnt work on firefox)

Comment: I think the web audio API is as good as it gets at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

The Web-Audio-API is a fairly new standard and is steadily being adopted by the major browsers with varying levels of support.  Currently Chrome and Safari have the best support and Firefox support is in it's [draft stage](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Web_Audio_API).  For the sort of application, with cross browser support, that you're wanting you will need to go to third party plugins/extensions/addons for the support you're after.

Welcome to the bleeding edge. :)